# Editing a sublime theme, how to know which key string corresponds to which text element in the code?

Tags: sublime-text-2, themes

I want to customize the color scheme of the comments in my code, by editing the `.tmTheme`

How to know which of the `<dict>` `<key>` corresponds to which element of the code?

[image]

Like, I can guess some of them but not every one of them is that obvious..

I remember there was some mouse click or a keyboard shortcut that when you hover over something in your code and click/press it it would show exactly the key you need to edit in the status bar.

Something like this [image]

How do I do that?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834765/where-to-find-a-list-of-scopes-for-sublime2-or-textmate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (OS X) to show the current scope names in the status bar.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

While Daniel Beck's answer works, and is technically correct, it's kind of a pain to keep pressing a key combination every time you want to see the scope. To that end, I highly recommend the [`ScopeAlways`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeAlways) plugin, available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). Once activated, it constantly displays the scope of the current cursor position in the status bar. I've found it invaluable for designing themes from the ground up, as well as just tweaking a selector here or there. (And no, I didn't write it...)